# cluster markers displaying inaccurately

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, cluster-manager

I've tried to implement the cluster manager following this [Google Developers toutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) but my markers are displaying extremely inaccurately compared to just using `googleMap.addMarker();`[(example)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker#add_a_map).

[Here is an image comparison of the two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo6CG.jpg)

I suppose it has to do with the `offset` in the `addClusterPoints()` but when I change the divisor(`60d`), the only change is how far the points are spread out but still an incorrect location. [I've tried changing the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJFXC.jpg) of `60d` and I've found that with <`60d` they are more spread out and >`60d` They are less spread out.

Could someone explain what the `offset` is doing and how to get the points to display accurately?

```
private void addClusterPoints(){
    List<LatLng> locations= new ArrayList<>(getLatLongList());
    for(int i=0; i < locations.size(); i++){
       double offset = i /60d;
       latLng = locations.get(i);
       double lat = latLng.latitude + offset;
       double lng = latLng.longitude + offset;
       mapClusterItem offsetItem = new mapClusterItem(lat, lng, "Tile "+i, "Snippet"+i);
       clusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: The offset is moving the markers' location by the offset amount - smaller divisor increases the offset and thus moves it farther north and east (first marker moved farther than last marker based on increasing numerator).  It's not clear what your motivation is for moving the markers - if you could expand on that it may be helpful.

Comment: You also have a potential issue with your loop: you create `locations` from some getter and then you access `sneezeLocations` with the loop index - seems like you should just use `locations`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the `sneezeLocations` is the same thing as the `locations` I just missed that when changing the name to make this question; but I've fixed it now.
Also, you are correct markers display in the correct locations when there is no offset.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy commented, the issue was in the `offset`. I've removed the `offset` and the markers are displaying at their expected locations.

The [Google Developers tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering) I referenced has the `offset` so I thought it was part of the process but it turns out it's completely unrelated. I honestly find it strange that they would decide to include that in the tutorial. The only reasoning I could think of why they would do that (since they don't provide one) would be to create some space between items that are very close together.